# my gpt 3.5 turbo api is not giving good enough response as i can get from chat gpt

Tags: reactjs, chat, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

So i have implemented chat gpt 3.5 turbo API in my react app. so my app is basically like an assistant to a recruiter. so a recruiter gives a sample job post to the app and it send this post to chat gpt to craft it. now i have different personas to be copied in the response i am also instructing it to follow these personas and styles. in this example persona of Lou Adler and style is enticing. But the problem is when i give the problem to cht gpt it is givng me good response but in case of my API in my app the response is not good enough. can someone tell me about the problem.

below is my code and note that there are two user roles. i do not understand this. where will the actual propt by user will be? can you kindly elaborate this problem.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


function App() {

 // get api key from server
  const [apiKey, setApiKey] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://server-khaki-kappa.vercel.app/api/key')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setApiKey(data.apiKey))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, []);
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
  };

  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
    system: '',
    user: '',
    assistant: '',
    prompt: '',
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-16k',
  });

  console.log(userInput)
  const [assistantResponse, setAssistantResponse] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleUserInput = (e) => {
    console.log('e.target',e.target.value);
    setUserInput((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const sendUserInput = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const data = {
      model: userInput.model,
      messages: [
        {
          role: 'system',
          content: 
          // userInput.system
          'You are an AI language model trained to assist recruiters in refining job posts. Please provide Enticing content, language, and information in the job posts. Number of words in the response should be equal to or more than the job post that a recruiter is giving to you. you strictly have to follow the same persona given to you. also you have to follow the job post that recruiter will give you. you will make it more enticing and follow the persona of Lou Adler'
             },
        {
          role: 'user',
          content: 
          userInput.user 
          // 'When rewriting the job description, use a language model acting as a recruitment expert or consultant. In this context, take on the persona of Lou Adler. Your role is to be enticing with the reader and emphasize the benefits and opportunities associated with the job position, while presenting the information in an enticing manner.'
            },
        {
          role: 'assistant',
          content:
            // userInput.assistant 
            'You are an AI assistant trained to help recruiters refine their job posts. You can provide suggestions, make the language more enticing, and ensure all necessary information is included. If any details are missing or ambiguous, please ask for more information to provide the best possible suggestions. Take your time to answer the best.'
             },
        {
          role: 'user',
          content:
            userInput.prompt 
            },
      ],
      temperature: 0.2
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
        data,
        { headers }
      );
      const { choices } = response.data;
      const assistantResponse = choices[0].message.content;
      setLoading(false);
      setAssistantResponse(assistantResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
    }
  };

  const formatAssistantResponse = (response) => {
    const paragraphs = response.split('\n\n');

    const formattedResponse = paragraphs.map((paragraph, index) => (
      <p key={index} className="text-left mb-4">
        {paragraph}
      </p>
    ));

    return formattedResponse;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto py-8">
    <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Chat :</h1>
    {loading ? (
      <>
        <h1 className="spinner"></h1>
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        <div className="bg-gray-100 p-4 mb-4">
          {formatAssistantResponse(assistantResponse)}
        </div>
      </>
    )}

    <section className='m-6'>
      
    <div className="mb-4 ">
      <label className="block mb-2">
        Model:
        <select
          className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
          name="model"
          value={userInput.model}
          onChange={handleUserInput}
        >
          <option value="gpt-3.5-turbo">gpt-3.5-turbo</option>
          <option value="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k">gpt-3.5-turbo-16k</option>
          <option value="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613">gpt-3.5-turbo-0613</option>
          <option value="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613">gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613</option>
          {/* <option value="text-davinci-003">text-davinci-003</option> */}
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div className="mb-4">
      {/* <label className="block mb-2">
        System Role:
        <textarea
           className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
          type="text"
          rows={4}
          name="system"
          value={userInput.system}
          onChange={handleUserInput}
        />
      </label> */}
    </div>
    <div className="mb-4">
<label className="block mb-2">
  User Role:
  <textarea
     className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
    rows={4}
    name="user"
    value={userInput.user}
    onChange={handleUserInput}
  />
</label>
</div>

    <div className="mb-4">
      {/* <label className="block mb-2">
        Assistant Role:
        <textarea
      
     
        className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
          type="text"
          rows={4}
          name="assistant"
          value={userInput.assistant}
          
          onChange={handleUserInput}
        />
      </label> */}
    </div>
    <div className="mb-4">
      <label className="block mb-2">
        Prompt:
        <textarea
          className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
          name='prompt'
          type="text"
          rows={4}
        onChange={handleUserInput}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
   
    </section>
    <button
      className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
      onClick={sendUserInput}
    >
      Send
    </button>
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The default temperature for Chat GPT is .7, having it set at .2 will generate much less creative, albeit more coherent, content.

The assistant role should also be in the perspective of the AI. It can be used to add context in a series of messages.

https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7042661-chatgpt-api-transition-guide